# Are countable sets meagre?

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

Countable sets have measure zero. Given the analogies between sets of measure zero and meagre sets (both modelling some idea of "smallness"), are countable sets meagre?

If this is true in some spaces but not others, I would be particularly interested to find out if countable sets are meagre in the Cantor space.

Comment: The definition of "meager" is "covered by countably many closed sets with empty interiors". So your question boils down to "are singletons meager?" So in $T_1$ spaces, the answer is yes iff there are no isolated points.

Comment: What is your definition of meagre set?

Comment: Thank you Andreas for your reply. May I ask you why, in a T_1 space (hence in the Cantor space) the absence of isolated points is a necessary and sufficient condition for countable sets to be meagre?

Comment: If x is isolated, any closed set containing x would not have @Curious, empty interior.

Comment: Ah, yes, OK. Thank you William for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

In a $T_1$ space without isolated points (such spaces are often called dense in themselves or "crowded") this holds, as then a countable set $D$ is just $\bigcup \{\{d\} : d \in D\}$ and each set $\{d\}$ is nowhere dense (closed by $T_1$ and its closure, i.e. $\{d\}$, has empty interior as $d$ is not isolated in $X$). And meagre sets are just countable unions of nowhere dense sets by definition.

The Cantor set is of course just such a space.

If you're interested in these topics, check out the book "Measure and Category" by Oxtoby, a nicely self-contained exploration of the analogues between things like sets of measure $0$ and meagre sets. It starts with the classic example of writing $\mathbb{R} = M \cup N$ where $N$ is a null set (has Lebesgue measure $0$) and $M$ is meagre. To see how different such "small" sets can be.